# Javascript - Insert spaces after numbers in textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to insert a space after 4 numbers within a textbox.

Example: XXXX XXXX XXXX

I've been able to get the spacing with no arrow keys or arrow keys with no spacing.

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260238/how-to-insert-space-every-4-characters-for-iban-registering) question and a few others on the site but I've been unable to solve the issue of the backspace and arrow keys.

Here is my code:

```
function isNumber(event) {
    event = (event) ? event : window.event;
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

And here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/3204/#fork) for it. This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ffwAA/4/) is very close but I haven't quite got the spacing correct.

Is this possible to do with my current function or do I need to approach this in a different manner?

**EDIT**: Is it possible to add arrow key functionality without the cursor allows returning to the back after being released?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/Lm2hS/3205/)

Problem is You have used keypress events.

```
 <input type="text" id="test" maxlength="14" name="test" 
     onkeyup="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Same function from the answer you referred

```
  function isNumber(e) {
   e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').
                      replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
 }
```

[This Article](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) will clearly explain why `keyup` and `keydown` event works but not `keypress`

To allow arrow keys [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/Lm2hS/3213/)

You have to use `keydown` event

Comment: What is wrong with the `keypress` event... You made it work but you should have justification as well...

Comment: Is it possible to allow arrow keys? If you try arrowing to the left and release the key, the cursor moves to the back.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you use oninput event that takes care of keyword paste and mouse paste

```
 <input type="text" id="test" maxlength="14" name="test" oninput="return isNumber(event)" />
```

js:

```
function isNumber(e) {
     e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see why you're sticking with the keypress event, so this function should make what you want to do possible.

Please read the notes inside the commented area's, I try to explain what it's doing.

I'm not very good with regex yet, but thanks to the other answer, I think this one will work best.

Code using REgex from @Gops AB:

```
function isNumber(event,el) {
    event = (event) ? event : window.event;

    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    //Add a space after 4 numbers.


    var v=el.value + String.fromCharCode(charCode); //Keypress does not let us see the value of the text box after the press, so we have to add the string to our comparison.
    v=v.replace(/\s/g,'');

    el.value=v.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim(); // using regex from other answer. Thanks @Gops AB for the example
    return false;
}
```

Demo with using Regex:
http://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/Lm2hS/3208/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shorthand most efficient way:

//HTML

```
<input type="text" id="cc" name="cc" maxlength="19">
```

//JS

```
init=()=>document.getElementById('cc').addEventListener('keyup',(e)=>e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim());
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```