# html input pattern with 2 patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Is it possible to have a input pattern with 2 options?

For example.
I have a field where a user enters an extension number (4 Digits) eg. 7483
BUT 
Some people have 2 extensions eg. 7483 / 7542

Is there a way to set the input pattern so it can either be 4 characters or 11? And otherwise show a error message?

This is what I have so far:

```
Extension:<br><input type="text" name="extension" required
pattern= "{4}" title="Please Enter the Extension Number/s"><br />
```

Comment: You can achieve it with Regex.

Comment: Never used Regex before I will look into it thank you!

Comment: Ur welcome. There is a very useful open source library for form validation named [jQuery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/). Make sure to check it & read thorough. For your special case you need to [write custom validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/#custom-validators).

Comment: so like this? \w{4}|\w{11}

Comment: Nice Fast Try! But thats wrong. Try a bit more. If you couldn't find design the right pattern, I'll send it to you. But Its better to read & think more Dude!

Comment: I checked that list but it doesnt show the option for 2 patterns? Mind helping me out? Also please post it as an answer so i can mark it correct :D

Comment: I posted it. Copy, Paste & Think about it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/) lib & write custom validator for it. For validation you should use `/^\d{4}( \/ \d{4})?$/` pattern.

Here is the complete solution. Read it thorough & stick with RegExp! ;-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom Validation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Extension:<br />
        <input type="text" name="extension" required
               data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^\d{4}( \/ \d{4})?$" title="Please Enter the Extension Number/s"><br />
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Setup form validation
        $.validate();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery or a plugin for this. Just enter the regex `^\d{4}( \/ \d{4})?$` into the `pattern` attribute and HTML5 takes care of the validation.

Comment: TY. My goal was to introduce the mentioned lib. It has many useful features for validation.

Comment: Well, in that case, there's actually a [regex validator built in](http://www.formvalidator.net/#default-validators_custom) :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Answer Updated Dude!

Comment: Thank you you guys are rock stars :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.

```
<input type="text" name="extension" required pattern=".{4}|.{11}" title="Please Enter the Extension Number/s">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/37ohqswp/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use regex match, keypress event listener and replace. Please see below for suggested answer. In addition, I have put the code on https://jsfiddle.net/8p590mhq/ for test. Hope this helps.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ext</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div>
     Extension:<br>
     <input type="text" id="extension" name="extension" placeholder="Please enter phone ext's" required>
   </div>
   <!-- JavaScript file include -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
//ammend field function
let ammend_field = () => {
 //get element by id
 let ext = document.getElementById("extension");

 //use regex match to replace ext.value input field
 //original answer from:
 //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260238/how-to-insert-space-every-4-characters-for-iban-registering
 ext.value = ext.value.replace(/[^\d0-9]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 / ').trim();
}

//add event listener to submit button
document.getElementById("extension").addEventListener("keypress", ammend_field);
```