# How to enter whitespace only once after 4 characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hey I have a input where the user enters his social security number. To make the input more readable I want to insert a whitespace after the first 4 characters of the string. The social security number itself is 10 numbers long. So the result should looke like: 1234 567890. I only found solutions where a whitespace every 4 characters is inserted but no example which is similar to this. Has someone an idea how to solve this?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" @keyup="insertWhitespace()"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert space every 4 characters for IBAN registering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260238/how-to-insert-space-every-4-characters-for-iban-registering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the use of Regular Expression + HTML DOM Element addEventListener().

Reference Website For "**Regular Expression**":  https://regexr.com/

With the help of a regular expression is a sequence of characters that specifies a search pattern in text or strings.

```js
document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/, '$1 ').trim();
});
```

```html
<input id="example" maxlength="11" name="example" />
```

Comment: @FloHaberfellner Welcome :), you can read about Regular Expression, and how it exactly works.  on a given website.

Comment: @Martijn Dear First read the user question clearly, they want to insert whitespace after the first 4 characters of the string.   So the result should look like:  1234 567890, they don't want white space after every 4 characters just read the question once again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution (Javascript) to your problem:

The code below reads the input value and remove alphabets and then replaces the digit value with the appropriate space character only once as expected after 4 digits.

```js
function insertWhitespace() {
 document.getElementById('myElement').value = document.getElementById('myElement').value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/, '$1 ').trim()
}
```

```html
<input id="myElement" maxlength="11" onkeyup="insertWhitespace()" />
```

Comment: I think the code is self-explanatory even to the novice

Comment: I've normalized it a little. Maybe a `onkeyup="insertWhitespace(this)"` would be more elegant, more broadly usable, but thats up to you

Comment: I have added explanation

Comment: This only lets you enter 9 numbers. maxlength should be 11.

Comment: The questioner limited it to 10 characters in the input as per his needs in the question itself. I am just presenting the solution to his problem

Comment: I have updated the max-length to 11  to accommodate 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your max length to 11 because white space also counts and try it with the following code

```
const ssn =  document.querySelector("selector");
ssn.addEventListener("keyup",(e) => {
  if(e.target.value.length === 4){
    ssn.value += " "
  }
})
```

Comment: Supose you write "1234" and want to backspace. You cant :)